# How to use read more/read less jquery script on more than 1 div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so, I have a jquery script that was written for read more/read less on divs, but i want to use it on more than 1 div without the More... button opening up all the divs on the page, how do I do this?

here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/S2mCv/

the code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){

// Resize Height
function reh(e) {
    $(e).css({'height':$(e).attr('height')})
}

// Empty Height
function emh(e) {
    $(e).css({'height':'auto'});
}

// Resize .lead (default height)
reh('.lead');

// Actions
// More: Lead
$('body').on('click', '.more-lead', function(){
    emh('.lead');
    $('.more-lead').html('Less...');
    $('.more-lead').addClass('less-lead').removeClass('more-lead');
});

// Less: Lead
$('body').on('click', '.less-lead', function(){
    reh('.lead');
    $('.less-lead').html('More...');
    $('.less-lead').addClass('more-lead').removeClass('less-lead');
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/S2mCv/1/

```
// More: Lead
$('body').on('click', '.more-lead', function(){
    emh($(this).siblings('.lead'));
    $(this).html('Less...').addClass('less-lead').removeClass('more-lead');
});

// Less: Lead
$('body').on('click', '.less-lead', function(){
    reh($(this).siblings('.lead'));
    $(this).html('More...').addClass('more-lead').removeClass('less-lead');
});
```

You are targeting all of a class. You should be targeting specifically the elements you need expanded or collapsed. By finding siblings, you can do this pretty easily.
Also, using `$(this)` keeps the reference on the clicked element instead of re-selecting all `.more-lead` or all `.less-lead` generically.

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/